# Raspberry Pi 3 Wont show any power LEDs

Tags: pi-3, troubleshooting

I just was lucky enough to win a Raspberry Pi 3 at a school fair. I inserted an SD card with the boot image and gave it power. However, the green LED would not flash to show it was booting. I have flashed the same image onto the card multiple times and it still wont work.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-downloading the image because it may be corrupt, another issue may be that your SD card has come to the end of its life and you will need a new one.

Comment: Thanks so much, i was starting to think that the pi was broken!

Answer (score 0):

If the green light never comes on it is rejecting the SD card, either:

- The SD card was not formatted properly.
- The SD card is no good.
- The Pi is broken.

Note this potentially isn't true for the Pi 2, where instead the green LED will come on and stay on rather than being off.